# WSO2 SAML Extension Grant

Tags: spring-security, wso2, wso2-api-manager, spring-saml, wso2-identity-server

I have configured WSO2 API Manager 2.0.0 (port 9443), Identity Server 5.1.0 (port 9444) and custom Spring application with SAML (port 22222). Application do login via SAML SSO on Identity Server and get assertion from Identity Server.

I want to do requests to APIs configured in API Manager through SAML SSO from my application. I configured API Manager and Identity Server like in [this](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM200/SAML+Extension+Grant) tutorial, but after login I get error:

```
{"error_description":"Provided Authorization Grant is invalid","error":"invalid_grant"}
```

Also read [this](http://xacmlinfo.org/2014/10/31/saml2-bearer-assertion-profile-for-oauth-2-0/) tutorial, but everything do not working.
My assertion looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><saml2:Assertion xmlns:saml2="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:assertion" ID="ofmidejjjopkijhmgbdpmmbnooliloalcdfmeiid" IssueInstant="2016-12-27T11:50:56.612Z" Version="2.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"><saml2:Issuer Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:entity">localhost</saml2:Issuer><ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#"><ds:SignedInfo><ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"/><ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1"/><ds:Reference URI="#ofmidejjjopkijhmgbdpmmbnooliloalcdfmeiid"><ds:Transforms><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature"/><ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#"><ec:InclusiveNamespaces xmlns:ec="http://www.w3.org/2001/10/xml-exc-c14n#" PrefixList="xs"/></ds:Transform></ds:Transforms><ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1"/><ds:DigestValue/></ds:Reference></ds:SignedInfo><ds:SignatureValue/><ds:KeyInfo><ds:X509Data><ds:X509Certificate>MIICNTCCAZ6gAwIBAgIES343gjANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQUFADBVMQswCQYDVQQGEwJVUzELMAkGA1UECAwCQ0ExFjAUBgNVBAcMDU1vdW50YWluIFZpZXcxDTALBgNVBAoMBFdTTzIxEjAQBgNVBAMMCWxvY2FsaG9zdDAeFw0xMDAyMTkwNzAyMjZaFw0zNTAyMTMwNzAyMjZaMFUxCzAJBgNVBAYTAlVTMQswCQYDVQQIDAJDQTEWMBQGA1UEBwwNTW91bnRhaW4gVmlldzENMAsGA1UECgwEV1NPMjESMBAGA1UEAwwJbG9jYWxob3N0MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCUp/oV1vWc8/TkQSiAvTousMzOM4asB2iltr2QKozni5aVFu818MpOLZIr8LMnTzWllJvvaA5RAAdpbECb+48FjbBe0hseUdN5HpwvnH/DW8ZccGvk53I6Orq7hLCv1ZHtuOCokghz/ATrhyPq+QktMfXnRS4HrKGJTzxaCcU7OQIDAQABoxIwEDAOBgNVHQ8BAf8EBAMCBPAwDQYJKoZIhvcNAQEFBQADgYEAW5wPR7cr1LAdq+IrR44iQlRG5ITCZXY9hI0PygLP2rHANh+PYfTmxbuOnykNGyhM6FjFLbW2uZHQTY1jMrPprjOrmyK5sjJRO4d1DeGHT/YnIjs9JogRKv4XHECwLtIVdAbIdWHEtVZJyMSktcyysFcvuhPQK8Qc/E/Wq8uHSCo=</ds:X509Certificate></ds:X509Data></ds:KeyInfo></ds:Signature><saml2:Subject><saml2:NameID Format="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress">admin@carbon.super</saml2:NameID><saml2:SubjectConfirmation Method="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:cm:bearer"><saml2:SubjectConfirmationData InResponseTo="a2chdg2i14ii0edi5682815gja848e0" NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-27T11:55:56.612Z" Recipient="http://localhost:22222/console/saml/SSO"/></saml2:SubjectConfirmation></saml2:Subject><saml2:Conditions NotBefore="2016-12-27T11:50:56.612Z" NotOnOrAfter="2016-12-27T11:55:56.612Z"><saml2:AudienceRestriction><saml2:Audience>onGeoConsoleTest2</saml2:Audience><saml2:Audience>http://localhost:22222/console/saml/SSO</saml2:Audience></saml2:AudienceRestriction></saml2:Conditions><saml2:AuthnStatement AuthnInstant="2016-12-27T11:50:56.613Z" SessionIndex="1644a04d-8b72-45b0-8e41-f3d809111355"><saml2:AuthnContext><saml2:AuthnContextClassRef>urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:Password</saml2:AuthnContextClassRef></saml2:AuthnContext></saml2:AuthnStatement><saml2:AttributeStatement><saml2:Attribute Name="role" NameFormat="urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:attrname-format:basic"><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/subscriber</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/ongeo-auth</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/api-store</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/everyone</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">admin</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/api-publisher</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/ongeo-console</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/cg_unpublisher</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Application/admin_Testujemy_PRODUCTION</saml2:AttributeValue><saml2:AttributeValue xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:type="xs:string">Internal/cg_publisher</saml2:AttributeValue></saml2:Attribute></saml2:AttributeStatement></saml2:Assertion>
```

API Manager Identity Provider Configuration:

[image: APIM1]

[image: APIM2]

Identity Server Service Provider configuration:

[image: ISSP]

Please, help!

UPDATE:

Expanded problem (SignatureValue and DigestValue are empty, maybe there is a problem):

> TID: [-1234] [] [2016-12-27 14:24:04,746] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.saml.SAML2BearerGrantHandler} -  Error while validating the signature. {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.saml.SAML2BearerGrantHandler}
>   org.opensaml.xml.validation.ValidationException: Unable to evaluate key against signature
>       at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:74)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.handlers.grant.saml.SAML2BearerGrantHandler.validateGrant(SAML2BearerGrantHandler.java:458)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.token.AccessTokenIssuer.issue(AccessTokenIssuer.java:194)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2.OAuth2Service.issueAccessToken(OAuth2Service.java:219)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:246)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.endpoint.token.OAuth2TokenEndpoint.issueAccessToken(OAuth2TokenEndpoint.java:110)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.performInvocation(AbstractInvoker.java:188)
>       at org.apache.cxf.service.invoker.AbstractInvoker.invoke(AbstractInvoker.java:104)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:204)
>       at org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.JAXRSInvoker.invoke(JAXRSInvoker.java:101)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor$1.run(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:58)
>       at org.apache.cxf.interceptor.ServiceInvokerInterceptor.handleMessage(ServiceInvokerInterceptor.java:94)
>       at org.apache.cxf.phase.PhaseInterceptorChain.doIntercept(PhaseInterceptorChain.java:272)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.ChainInitiationObserver.onMessage(ChainInitiationObserver.java:121)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.http.AbstractHTTPDestination.invoke(AbstractHTTPDestination.java:249)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invokeDestination(ServletController.java:248)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:222)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.ServletController.invoke(ServletController.java:153)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFNonSpringServlet.invoke(CXFNonSpringServlet.java:171)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.handleRequest(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:289)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.doPost(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:209)
>       at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
>       at org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.AbstractHTTPServlet.service(AbstractHTTPServlet.java:265)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:120)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
>       at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:505)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:169)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.continueInvocation(CompositeValve.java:99)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonTomcatValve$1.invoke(CarbonTomcatValve.java:47)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.webapp.mgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:57)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.event.receiver.core.internal.tenantmgt.TenantLazyLoaderValve.invoke(TenantLazyLoaderValve.java:48)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.TomcatValveContainer.invokeValves(TomcatValveContainer.java:47)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CompositeValve.invoke(CompositeValve.java:62)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.invoke(CarbonStuckThreadDetectionValve.java:159)
>       at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:956)
>       at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.valves.CarbonContextCreatorValve.invoke(CarbonContextCreatorValve.java:57)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
>       at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:436)
>       at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1078)
>       at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:625)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1749)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(NioEndpoint.java:1708)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
>   Caused by: org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 0 but was expecting 128
>   Original Exception was java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 0 but was expecting 128
>       at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.implementations.SignatureBaseRSA.engineVerify(SignatureBaseRSA.java:93)
>       at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.SignatureAlgorithm.verify(SignatureAlgorithm.java:301)
>       at org.apache.xml.security.signature.XMLSignature.checkSignatureValue(XMLSignature.java:723)
>       at org.opensaml.xml.signature.SignatureValidator.validate(SignatureValidator.java:69)
>       ... 58 more
>   Caused by: java.security.SignatureException: Signature length not correct: got 0 but was expecting 128
>       at sun.security.rsa.RSASignature.engineVerify(RSASignature.java:190)
>       at java.security.Signature$Delegate.engineVerify(Signature.java:1174)
>       at java.security.Signature.verify(Signature.java:624)
>       at org.apache.xml.security.algorithms.implementations.SignatureBaseRSA.engineVerify(SignatureBaseRSA.java:91)
>       ... 61 more

Comment: certificate alias is usually wso2carbon and not wso2carbon.cert in SP config

Comment: Also you can enable debug logs for oauth component to get more details of the error.  add an entry for org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth2=DEBUG in log4j.properties of APIM found in the conf folder for more details of the error

Comment: @farasath, thank you! First of all, error was with audience and recipient urls, must be ip address instead of `localhost`. Second, my signature and digest is empty and I don't know why :\ See UPDATE

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41284297/saml2bearergranthandler-unable-to-verify-signature?noredirect=1#comment69888152_41284297

Comment: Also you need to send the assertion in base64urlencoded format

Comment: @farasath, already read this post and send the assertion in base64urlencoded format. Problem was in Spring SAML extension. Solved.

Comment: better to post an answer for the benefit of future references.

Comment: @farasath, marked as duplicate